# How to scale a dirtree inside a figure?

Tags: floats, boxes, scaling, dirtree

I drew a tree structure with `\dirtree`. This tree is located in a `{figure}` environment. It is possible to adjust the size of the figure?

With `\includegraphics` one can do it with `scale`. Is there a similar attribute for figure?

**My code looks like this (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\label{fig:directory}       
\fbox{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
                CSS3
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                        .3 style.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 div (square).
                            .4 div (card).
                }
            \end{minipage}
            %
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
                SVG
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                        .3 style.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 svg.
                            .4 image.
                                .5 animateTransform.
                }
            \end{minipage}  
            %
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
                Canvas
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 canvas.
                        .4 script.
                }
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
  }%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: There is `\resizebox` and `\scalebox`.

Comment: Take a look at the `adjustbox` package, which provides a nice key=value interface to all box-related LaTeX commands. With a single `adjustbox` environment, you could rplace the `fbox`, `parbox` **and** scale/resize the content.

Comment: dirtree is just text, so you could use `\scalebox` and friends but it's usually better with text just to select a smaller fontsize as that gives more regular output. so `\footnotesize`  or `\small` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

`dirtree` is just text, so you could use `\scalebox` and friends but it's usually better with text just to select a smaller fontsize as that gives more regular output. so `\footnotesize` or `\small` or whatever.

[image]

I used `\small` here, I also fixed several other spacing issues (you need to allow space for the fbox rules and padding when allocating the width to the outer `\parbox` Also you need to beware of word spaces between the minipages. Rather than shrink too much, I allowed the central tree box to overlap the right hand one as the actual trees don't overlap, and I added float package so that `H` means "Here`rather than an unreported syntax error that makes the float go the end of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree,float}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{figure}[H]
\label{fig:directory}       
\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
            \centering\small
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
                CSS3
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                        .3 style.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 div (square).
                            .4 div (card).
                }
            \end{minipage}\hfill
            %
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth+50pt\relax}
                SVG
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                        .3 style.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 svg.
                            .4 image.
                                .5 animateTransform.
                }
            \end{minipage}\hspace{-50pt}\hfill 
            %
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
                Canvas
                \dirtree{%
                .1 html.
                    .2 head.
                        .3 title.
                        .3 meta.
                    .2 body.
                        .3 canvas.
                        .4 script.
                }
            \end{minipage}

  }%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```